# Make canvas background have a transparent rect

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I want a colored canvas cover layer and it has a transparent rect hole for showing the back `div`.

The `clip()` method is a opposite operation in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, but you can draw a shape with a hole to clip the canvas.

```js
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = 300;
c.height=300;
ctx.fillStyle = "gold";

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,150);
ctx.lineTo(0,300);
ctx.lineTo(300,300);
ctx.lineTo(300,0);
ctx.lineTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(0,150);
ctx.lineTo(50,150);
ctx.lineTo(50,50);
ctx.lineTo(250,50);
ctx.lineTo(250,250);
ctx.lineTo(50,250);
ctx.lineTo(50,150);
ctx.closePath();

ctx.clip();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
```

```css
div,
canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
div {
  background: black;
}

p {
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div><p>The Div</p></div>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clearRect(x,y,width,height)`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) for  more detail.